# html link in swf object

Tags: html, flash, hyperlink

I have a swf file but I dont have the source. I need to add a  link to the object swf but I dont know how. I need to do something like this:

```
<a href='http://www.mypage.com'><object ....> </a>
```

is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You have to embed it:

```
<embed width="550" height="400" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" src="http://www.mypage.com" quality="high"></embed>
```

And then change the src attribute into the website where your swf is uploaded.